# How do I get a list of emails from Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If I'm using Devise with Rails, how do I go from:
User.all

to an array of email addresses that I can put into a select list?

Something like User.all.email?

Do I need to iterate over the list or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (only Ruby 1.9.2):

```
User.all.map(&:email)
```

This is a simple form allowing you to call a single method on each object and return the results in an array.

You can also (both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2):

```
User.all.map{|u| u.email}
```

This allows for more complex manipulation, like:

```
User.all.map{|u| [u.id, u.name + ": " + u.email]
```

Which of course returns a pair of id and a string containing name and email for each user.

Those methods actually have less to do with devise and more to do with [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html)

Comment: This worked well; is there anyway I can include user_id in the mapping? And maybe include some concatenation - e.g. :first_name + :last_name ?

Comment: Added more explanation. It is good to study methods from `Enumerable` - they make many tasks easier and the code cleaner.

Comment: Just want to say, thanks for this, definitely the most useful thing I've learnt all day.